# Textbox search in DatagridView & FIlters it Contents

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

The following code works, but i am searching for something more complex, that is when i type a character of the secondname or lastname in a defined Textbox, the whole name (firstname, secondname or lastname) is in a single column ("Nombre_Doctor") in the DB, so it just filter it search the sigle character in all the columns.

Or how can it be changed to when i place any value (number or char) it search on whole table, and filters it (fills again the DataGridView), cause in the code you can see that it Select * (all) from DOCTORS (table) WHERE Nombre_Doctor (just one column) ...etc

Thank you so much in advanced.

LC

```
private void txtsearchpa_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [DOCTORS] where Nombre_Doctor like ('" + txtsearchdr.Text + "%')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    DGV1.DataSource = dt; //DGV = DataGridView

    con.Close();  
}
```

Comment: So you want to enter "text" in the `TextBox` and the grid should filter out all rows except where "text" appears in *any* column, correct?

Comment: No, it must filter any "text" of the [TextBox] in that column, or even must filter any "text" and / or "number" of the [TextBox] in all columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do is to filter your GridView data based on a search, I suggest this:
You have a list or a collection where you have all the data. I have this example:

```
   IEnumerable<Product> ListProduct = from Prod in LstProducts where Prod.Description.StartsWith(txtFind.Text) select Prod;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (var item in ListProduct)
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.Status, item.Description, tipo.Price);
```

And filter the information in the column you want (Description) and using the filter you want (StartsWith), but for this you need to have a list of objects (LstProducts). I hope it has been helpful.